# Selling Android game with using Google Play Games

Tags: unity, android, google-play

I'm making an Android Game that using Google Play Games for authentication, and storing user data to cloud.

Originally I planned this game as free, and put some in-app-purchasement stuffs in it, but unfortunately there is a serious technical issue, so that I have to rid off IAP from my game.

I spent lots of my time to developing this game, and I want to get some reward from my work, so I decided to sell this stuff with reasonable cheap price, but is it ok to sell the game that using Google Play Games? I googled it already, but couldn't find any related information about this.

Comment: What would make this not OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's totally OK to use Google Play Games in both free and premium apps.

You just have to accept the [Google Play Games Services Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/games/services/terms)  and [Google APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/terms/).

You agree to accept these terms when you use the API.